# DNS Client Event 1012: Error reading local hosts file

Tags: windows-7, dns, hosts

My notebook boots extreme slowly and shows loads of the following error in the event log:

**Error reading local hosts file**
Source: DNS Client Events
EventID: 1012

The computer is quite new, I kind of just finished installing. So I don't feel like installing everything again (especially since this probably would result in the same problem anyway).

Any idea how to resolve this?

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your %SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\ directory for a "hosts" file, if it doesn't exists create it and add

127.0.0.1 localhost

to the file then save.

If you do have the file ensure it is readable by administrators, system and users.